# Finding values of a mapping/dict

Tags: javascript

I have map/dictionary in Javascript:

```
var m = {
   dog: "Pluto",
   duck: "Donald"
};
```

I know how to get the keys with `Object.keys(m)`, but how to get the values of the Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no similar function for that but you can use:

```
var v = Object.keys(m).map(function(key){
    return m[key];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just iterate over the keys and retrieve each value:

```
var values = [];
for (var key in m) {
    values.push(m[key]);
}
// values == ["Pluto", "Donald"]
```